# Apache2 - How to serve static files on a specific folder?

Tags: apache-2.4, configuration, static-files

I have 2 virtual hosts serving 2 different sites in my Ubuntu Server 20.04 both in port 80 and 443.

I want to use the same server to serve some static files for download on a custom port, let's say 8080.

I added a `share_backup_folder.conf` configuration file on my `/etc/apache2/sites-available` with the following content:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
        ServerName vpsxxxxx.ovh.net
        DocumentRoot /var/www/backup

        Alias /backup /var/www/backup
        <Directory /var/www/backup>
                Require all granted
                Options +Indexes
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I enabled it with
`sudo a2ensite share_backup_folder`
and restart apache2
`sudo systemctl restart apache2`
with no errors.

When I `wget vpsxxxxx.ovh.net:8080/backup/example_file.tar.gz` it fails with `Connection refused`

What am I missing here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You probably miss a

```
Listen 8080
```

and it prbably belons into `/etc/apache2/ports`.

Comment: That was it! Thank you!